# I'm getting error using struts2 in weblogic server

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, weblogic

I'm getting the below error `@ weblogic server`. Can anyone please help me?

```
<BEA-101020> <[weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext@3c6542 - appName: 'goutattack', name: 'goutattack', context-path: '', spec-version: '2.5'] Servlet failed with Exception
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletResponseImpl.sendError(ServletResponseImpl.java:643)
        at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.sendError(Dispatcher.java:852)
        at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:534)
        at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher.doFilter(FilterDispatcher.java:432)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:42)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3502)
        at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
        at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(Unknown Source)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2186)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2092)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(Unknown Source)
        at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:201)
        at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:173)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a known major issue, fixed in Struts v2.3.7. See: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/WW-3373

Also may be related to an issue with the Jasper plugin:

> When using mentioned plugin in Weblogic 11g you can get NullPointerException within Struts 2. To solve the problem you must enable the "Archived Real Path" global property in Weblogic admin console > configuration > Web Applications. It's because JasperReportsResult determines the report directory base on servletContext.getRealPath(finalLocation).

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/WW/WebLogic